# How to book Thai train tickets online for Train #40?

Tags: trains, public-transport, thailand, bangkok

I've tried booking tickets for Train #40 (BKK - Surat Thani line) via a couple of websites without success.
The following websites tell me "this trip is not bookable" (while tickets for other trains seem to be available...)

- https://www.train36.com/book-train-tickets-in-thailand-online.html
- https://12go.asia/en/checkout/107a2e59

From what I can gather the official website is
https://www.railway.co.th , but this one does not load...

Can anyone point me to a website that works specifically for train #40?

Comment: The Thai site loads for me. It just takes a lot of time, megabytes before displaying. Maybe wait longer or get a faster connection?

Comment: I suspect train #40 doesn't exist anymore, because it isn't listed on the Seat61 webpage for Thailand (https://www.seat61.com/Thailand.htm#Bangkok_to_Southern_Thailand).  That same webpage lists an assortment of other Thai trains of varying quality going from Bangkok to Surat Thani and beyond, just pick any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bangkok-Surat Thani is the Southern Line, but according to the [official timetable](https://ttsview.railway.co.th/SRT_Schedule2022.php?ln=th&line=4&trip=1) Train #40 runs *from* Surat Thani *to* Bangkok.  Perhaps this is why you're not seeing it?

In general, you can book Thai train tickets at the official [D Ticket](https://www.dticket.railway.co.th/DTicketPublicWeb/booking/booking) booking site, which is fortunately much more responsive than the main SRT site.

Also beware that Thai train schedules are currently in flux due to the repeatedly postponed relocation of the main Bangkok terminus from Hualamphong to Bang Sue, so check routes carefully. "Bangkok" in schedules refers to the old one.